# Laravel 5.1 Mail Queue not working after upgrading driver from sync to redis

Tags: laravel-5, redis

I recently setup my Redis server and configured laravel to use it. Everything is going fine, sessions are working cache is working. I set the queue driver to redis in env as well and tried Mail::queue function, apparently I am not getting any error but I don't see any mail in my inbox. When driver was set to sync I was getting emails. Is there something else I need to configure?

Comment: Do you have the queue listener running? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener

Comment: doesn't it apply to scenario where I want to run a custom queue? I mean doesn't laravel listen to Mail::queue by default?

Comment: totally got your point, ran the command and it is working now. Make your comment an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in the queue (mail and otherwise) sit there until processed by [the queue listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener).